# InertiaJS How to use "Nested Layouts" for tabs?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I was hoping to get some additional information about the "Nested Layouts" in InertiaJS. The documentation is very scarce on it and I can barely find any sort of examples showing how it works, and the documentation on the site isn't very descriptive about how it works or what the code is doing. (https://inertiajs.com/pages#persistent-layouts)

Basically I want to achieve functionality similar to in this tweet here;
https://twitter.com/klaasgeldof/status/1181198792995037184

Hopefully someone can provide some extra information because I've been having a lot of trouble getting this working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `<slot />` inside tab

Now the trick is to put two Layouts on the nested page.

https://inertiajs.com/pages

```
<script>
  import SiteLayout from './SiteLayout'
  import NestedLayout from './NestedLayout'

  export default {
    // Using a render function
    layout: (h, page) => {
      return h(SiteLayout, [
        h(NestedLayout, [page]),
      ])
    },

    // Using the shorthand
    layout: [SiteLayout, NestedLayout],

    props: {
      user: Object,
    },
  }
</script>
```

`layout: [SiteLayout, NestedLayout]` this is where the trick is.

Comment: is this available for vue 2?

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to this and I'd say they are more related to what your frontend stack is. Since this question is tagged with vue.js I'll answer based on that.

### Approach #1

The inertia part here is just creating a layout - which is basically just a vue component. That layout then contains the side and top navigation and a slot to fill the body content. You can then create a dashboard page component which utilize that layout by adding `layout: myDashboardLayout` in the export.

To get the same effect, you basically route to different views, which pass different slots to the layout and their respective data.

```html
    // Your DashboardLayout.vue
    <template>
        <div>
             <my-sidebar :data="foo" />
             <my-topbar :data="bar" />
             <slot name="dashboardContent" />
        </div>
    </template>
```

```html
    // Your Dashboard/Index.vue
    <template>
        <main slot="dashboardContent" :data="myData" />
    </template>
    
    <script>
      import DashboardLayout from './DashboardLayout'
    
      export default {
    
        // Using the shorthand
        layout: DashboardLayout,
    
      }
    </script>
```

```php
    //web.php
    
    Route::get('/dashboard', function(){
        return Inertia::render('Dashboard/Index', [data]);
    });
    
    Route::get('/dashboard/foo', function(){
        return Inertia::render('Dashboard/Index', [fooData]);
    });
    
    Route::get('/dashboard/bar', function(){
        return Inertia::render('Dashboard/Index', [barData]);
    });
```

You then either visit `domain.com/dashboard/foo` or `domain.com/dashboard/bar`

### Approach #2

Having the same layout view, but passing a "tab-view" component. You'd not switch the routes at all and provide that one tab-view component with props to render the three different tabs.

Depending on the data, this approach could be slower as you fetch everything up front.

With #1 you fetch the data on demand and since it's an SPA, the user would't notice a difference.

Another benefit of #1 is, the user can actually actively visit that one specific tab and bookmark its URL for frequent access. You could do the same with anchors/hashes but you're using an SPA after all.

I could go on, but choose either option or perhaps that was enough to give you some inspiration.